# What is the order of the IP addresses from WSAIoctl()?

Tags: sockets, winapi, ip, winsock

I'm interested to know, how does `WSAIoctl()` with the `SIO_ROUTING_INTERFACE_QUERY` control code create the list of IP addresses of my host machine? In particular, what criteria does it use to order the IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

It only returns one!  From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742282.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> SIO_ROUTING_INTERFACE_QUERY (opcode setting: I, O, T==1)
>   To obtain the address of **the** local interface (represented as sockaddr structure) that should be used to send to the remote address specified in the input buffer ...

It's true that multiple routes to the destination address might exist, in which case it will no doubt pick the cheapest (routing table entries each contain a *cost*, or metric, see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table)).

Or did you mean `SIO_ADDRESS_LIST_QUERY`?, in which case Windows knows full well what network interfaces you have installed on your machine and the order in which they are returned is supremely unimportant.

Comment: In my case, I have 2 IP Addresses and i'm interested if WSAIoctl() creates the list of my IP Addresses in a specific oreder or random.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.